# Pyopencl._cl.LogicError: clWaitForEvents failed: <unknown error -9999>

Tags: python, pyopencl

I'm solving some equations using pyopencl on GPU device. If I increase size of computational arrays I get:

```
launch.wait()
pyopencl._cl.LogicError: clWaitForEvents failed: <unknown error -9999>
```

If I try to run this size of problem on CPU, everything works fine. I have an 8 Gb memory GPU device and as I can see from memory I do not consume even 1Gb while running code on CPU.

If I remove `launch.wait()` then I receive

```
return _cl._enqueue_read_buffer(queue, src, dest, **kwargs)
pyopencl._cl.RuntimeError: clEnqueueReadBuffer failed: OUT_OF_RESOURCES
```

So why do I get this problem even if do not use all the resources?

Comment: There is a possibility that the same operations might consume more space on the GPU as they do on the CPU, although that highly depends on the internal implementation of pyopencl..